# Dropdown menu; hover css doesnot work on Sibling members but work on descendant members

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

There are two codes below. The codes are for dropdown menu. Both codes are almost same but with a little difference. I have created a main list item for the main menu and given it classes. Then I have created a submenu and given it classes menu. The main heading is given class heading and has  element in each of the element. 
When I apply ":hover" on (anchor element) element combined with on submenu(dropdown element) the code does not work. While if I apply ":hover" on class heading(class of  element) the drop down works. 
I am sharing the code to clarify and be more specific.
The following code works for the drop down menu and has hover on heading class. I have commented in the code of css to clarify which part of the code I am referring.

```css
.menu{
 padding: 20px;
 background: #d80000;
}
.mainmenu{
 display: flex;
 list-style: none;
}
.heading{
 margin-right: 1px;
}
.mainmenu .heading a{
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 10px;
 text-decoration: none;
 background: #fff;
 color: #d80000;
 width: 80px;
 text-align: center;
 position: relative;
}

.submenu{
 list-style: none;
 margin-left: -40px;
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
}

.submenu a{
 border-top: 3px solid #d80000;
 width: 80px;
}

.heading a:hover{
 background: #d80000;
 color: #fff;
}

/* Here the hover and submenu element works to make the element display as block*/
.heading:hover .submenu{
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<html>
 <head> 
  <title>Menu</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style5.css">
 </head>
 <body>
 <div class="menu">
   <ul class="mainmenu">
    <li class="heading"><a href="#">Home</a>
     <ul class="submenu">
      <li class="items"><a href="#">A</a></li>
      <li class="items"><a href="#">B</a></li>
      <li class="items"><a href="#">C</a></li>
      <li class="items"><a href="#">D</a></li>
      <li class="items"><a href="#">E</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="heading"><a href="#">About</a>
     <ul class="submenu">
      <li class="items"><a href="#">A</a></li>
      <li class="items"><a href="#">B</a></li>
      <li class="items"><a href="#">C</a></li>
      <li class="items"><a href="#">D</a></li>
      <li class="items"><a href="#">E</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="heading"><a href="#">Services</a>
     <ul class="submenu">
      <li class="items"><a href="#">A</a></li>
      <li class="items"><a href="#">B</a></li>
      <li class="items"><a href="#">C</a></li>
      <li class="items"><a href="#">D</a></li>
      <li class="items"><a href="#">E</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="heading"><a href="#">Products</a>
     <ul class="submenu">
      <li class="items"><a href="#">A</a></li>
      <li class="items"><a href="#">B</a></li>
      <li class="items"><a href="#">C</a></li>
      <li class="items"><a href="#">D</a></li>
      <li class="items"><a href="#">E</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="heading"><a href="#">Contact</a>
     <ul class="submenu">
      <li class="items"><a href="#">A</a></li>
      <li class="items"><a href="#">B</a></li>
      <li class="items"><a href="#">C</a></li>
      <li class="items"><a href="#">D</a></li>
      <li class="items"><a href="#">E</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Now I am going to post the code which is not working for the dropdown menu
In this the element  is applied with hover along with submenu class.

```css
.menu{
 padding: 20px;
 background: #d80000;
}
.mainmenu{
 display: flex;
 list-style: none;
}
.heading{
 margin-right: 1px;
}
.mainmenu .heading a{
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 10px;
 text-decoration: none;
 background: #fff;
 color: #d80000;
 width: 80px;
 text-align: center;
 position: relative;
}

.submenu{
 list-style: none;
 margin-left: -40px;
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
}

.submenu a{
 border-top: 3px solid #d80000;
 width: 80px;
}

.heading a:hover{
 background: #d80000;
 color: #fff;
}

/* Here the hover on a and submenu element doesnot works to make the element display as block*/
.heading a:hover .submenu{
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<html>
 <head> 
  <title>Menu</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style5.css">
 </head>
 <body>
 <div class="menu">
   <ul class="mainmenu">
    <li class="heading"><a href="#">Home</a>
     <ul class="submenu">
      <li class="items"><a href="#">A</a></li>
      <li class="items"><a href="#">B</a></li>
      <li class="items"><a href="#">C</a></li>
      <li class="items"><a href="#">D</a></li>
      <li class="items"><a href="#">E</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="heading"><a href="#">About</a>
     <ul class="submenu">
      <li class="items"><a href="#">A</a></li>
      <li class="items"><a href="#">B</a></li>
      <li class="items"><a href="#">C</a></li>
      <li class="items"><a href="#">D</a></li>
      <li class="items"><a href="#">E</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="heading"><a href="#">Services</a>
     <ul class="submenu">
      <li class="items"><a href="#">A</a></li>
      <li class="items"><a href="#">B</a></li>
      <li class="items"><a href="#">C</a></li>
      <li class="items"><a href="#">D</a></li>
      <li class="items"><a href="#">E</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="heading"><a href="#">Products</a>
     <ul class="submenu">
      <li class="items"><a href="#">A</a></li>
      <li class="items"><a href="#">B</a></li>
      <li class="items"><a href="#">C</a></li>
      <li class="items"><a href="#">D</a></li>
      <li class="items"><a href="#">E</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="heading"><a href="#">Contact</a>
     <ul class="submenu">
      <li class="items"><a href="#">A</a></li>
      <li class="items"><a href="#">B</a></li>
      <li class="items"><a href="#">C</a></li>
      <li class="items"><a href="#">D</a></li>
      <li class="items"><a href="#">E</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

So my question is why is the code working for the first code and not for the second code. The second code has hover on  element while the first code has hover on class of  element of the main menu.

Comment: Trying to do this sort of thing with only HTML and CSS leads to big accessibility problems. [Build an accessible menu instead](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2017/11/building-accessible-menu-systems/).

Comment: from what I scanned it uses JavaScript. Will go through it.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>  .heading a:hover .submenu
>                  ^
> ```

There you have a **descendant** combinator.

> ```
> <li class="heading"><a href="#">Home</a>
>      <ul class="submenu">
> ```

Here the `.submenu` is a **sibling** of the `a` element, not a descendant.

You need one of the [sibling combinators](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#sibling-combinators)

Comment: seems that as it was a sibling class it was not working or the code didnot do anything due to it being sibbling. Solved the problem when using the sibling combination

Answer (score 0):

You are not using `a` in the second one so use

```
.heading a:hover .submenu{
    display: block;
}
```

here you are making the mistake :

```
.heading:hover .submenu{
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [general sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator) to select `.submenu` siblings of `.heading a:hover`. EG:

```
.heading a:hover ~ .submenu{
    display: block;
}
```

However, now when you move your pointer down to the submenu itself you're no longer hovering on the `a` so the submenu will revert to `display:none;`, To resolve this we can insist that the `.submenu` themselves are `display:block;` when hovered. EG:

```
.heading .submenu:hover {
    display: block;
}
```

Working demo:

```css
.menu{
 padding: 20px;
 background: #d80000;
}
.mainmenu{
 display: flex;
 list-style: none;
}
.heading{
 margin-right: 1px;
}
.mainmenu .heading a{
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 10px;
 text-decoration: none;
 background: #fff;
 color: #d80000;
 width: 80px;
 text-align: center;
 position: relative;
}

.submenu{
 list-style: none;
 margin-left: -40px;
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
}

.submenu a{
 border-top: 3px solid #d80000;
 width: 80px;
}

.heading a:hover{
 background: #d80000;
 color: #fff;
}

/* Use general sibling selector to select .submenu siblings of .heading a:hover*/
.heading a:hover ~ .submenu{
 display: block;
}
/* however, now when you move your pointer down to the submenu itself you're no longer hovering on the a so the submenu will go back to display none; To resolve this we can insist that the submenu themselves are display block when hovered: */
.heading .submenu:hover {
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<html>
 <head> 
  <title>Menu</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style5.css">
 </head>
 <body>
 <div class="menu">
   <ul class="mainmenu">
    <li class="heading"><a href="#">Home</a>
     <ul class="submenu">
      <li class="items"><a href="#">A</a></li>
      <li class="items"><a href="#">B</a></li>
      <li class="items"><a href="#">C</a></li>
      <li class="items"><a href="#">D</a></li>
      <li class="items"><a href="#">E</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="heading"><a href="#">About</a>
     <ul class="submenu">
      <li class="items"><a href="#">A</a></li>
      <li class="items"><a href="#">B</a></li>
      <li class="items"><a href="#">C</a></li>
      <li class="items"><a href="#">D</a></li>
      <li class="items"><a href="#">E</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="heading"><a href="#">Services</a>
     <ul class="submenu">
      <li class="items"><a href="#">A</a></li>
      <li class="items"><a href="#">B</a></li>
      <li class="items"><a href="#">C</a></li>
      <li class="items"><a href="#">D</a></li>
      <li class="items"><a href="#">E</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="heading"><a href="#">Products</a>
     <ul class="submenu">
      <li class="items"><a href="#">A</a></li>
      <li class="items"><a href="#">B</a></li>
      <li class="items"><a href="#">C</a></li>
      <li class="items"><a href="#">D</a></li>
      <li class="items"><a href="#">E</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="heading"><a href="#">Contact</a>
     <ul class="submenu">
      <li class="items"><a href="#">A</a></li>
      <li class="items"><a href="#">B</a></li>
      <li class="items"><a href="#">C</a></li>
      <li class="items"><a href="#">D</a></li>
      <li class="items"><a href="#">E</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks..your answer clearly specifies the problem and solves it to get the result.